# Who were these two 1961 Soviet pilot defectors?

Tags: soviet-union

During the Viet Nam War, a Soviet pilot nicknamed "Victor" defected from an airbase near Baku, crash landing in Iran in an L-29. In the USAF he was named "Defector Source 306".

An earlier incident of the same type is described in the Wikipedia in the following words:

> In 1961, a disappointed Soviet pilot flew his Sukhoi Su-9 interceptor
>   to Abadan, Iran. Only very sketchy details about this incident are
>   known even today, but the plane and the pilot were quickly picked up
>   by officers of the Foreign Technology Division (FTD) of the United
>   States DoD. After being disassembled within 24 hours the Su-9 was
>   transported to the USA, while the pilot followed shortly after. *[Cold War Pilot Defections, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cold_War_pilot_defections)*

What was the identity of these two pilots?

Comment: Perhaps there is confusion here with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Belenko?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Belenko flew from airbase near Vladivostok in MiG-25 and landed in Japan. This could hardly be confused with any other case.

Answer (score 6):

> During the Viet Nam War, a Soviet pilot nicknamed "Victor" defected from an airbase near Baku, crash landing in Iran in an L-29. In the USAF he was named "Defector Source 306".

This is probably the same incident mentioned in [Russian wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B):

> 1973 год лётчик-ин­структор Армавирского училища *Сафронов* перелетел в Иран

This [site](http://www.v3let.ru/historia/301-ugmigov.html) claims that "Сафронов" is actually *Сафронов Юрий Николаевич*, graduate of Eisk Air Force School (aka EVVAUL) in 1968. This name actually presents in the alumni list on [EVVAUL alumni site](http://evvaul.com), but there's no further information available.

> In 1961, a disappointed Soviet pilot flew his Sukhoi Su-9 interceptor to Abadan, Iran

Absolutely nothing except the cited fragment. Sometimes even thought to be a fake. See [this discussion](http://forums.airforce.ru/holodnaya-voina/4757-ugon-su-9-a), for example.

Answer (score 1):

My father used to talk so much about a man he had met in the 60's and who became friend after. He was a former soviet aircraft pilot who had defected with his plane. His name was LESLIE, and he was engaged with another foreign woman in São Paulo, Brazil.

Mr Leslie had suggested to my father a new business in textiles and they were planning to startup together. All this had taken place probably from 1967 to 1968. Mr. Leslie was a very intelligent and smart man, and I presume he had lived in Brazil for at least 2 years earlier or more that's because he had learnt how to speak portuguese as well (with accents for sure, but fluently).

Mr Leslie used to tell to my father his life story, and how he had defected with his plane. Once he showed to my father a photo in the newspaper with his soviet plane. Those stories about defection in the news were, in truth, Mr Leslie's stories (I suppose it Was 'The Sukhoi Su 9' case, that's because the dates match ). But at the same time, he didn't used to talk very often about those issues, he didn't Like to. His wife had taught my mother how to cook a "fondue", a swiss specialty.

After a while, Mr Leslie and his wife mysteriously disappeared from São Paulo, and my father never knew to where, why, how come, nothing at all. Simply Mr Leslie and his wife have haven't given any notices about themselves since 1968. That was a mystery!